# Why is צדקתך reversed for Ashkenazim and Sefardim?

Tags: nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

After Shemoneh Esrei at Shabbos mincha we say צדקתך which consists of 3 pesukim. However the order of these pesukim for the Ashkenazim is the exact opposite order for the Sefardim. Why the difference?

Potentially helpful- I did notice that the order Sefardim say it in is probably better and more original because that’s the order of when the pesukim appear in Tehillim, so then the question becomes why did the Ashkenazim flip it?

Comment: "more original" on the contrary: lectio difficilior potior